# PostgreSQL: from OID to Bytea

Tags: postgresql, oid

We have decided to move from `OID`s in our PostgreSQL 9.0 database and use `bytea` columns instead. I'm trying to copy the data from one column to the other, but I can't figure out the right query. This is the closest I've gotten to:

```
update user as thistable set pkcs_as_bytea = (select array_agg(mylargeobject.data) from 
  (select * from pg_largeobject where loid = thistable.pkcs12_as_oid order by pageno) as mylargeobject) where thistable.pkcs12 is not null
```

And that gives me the following error message:

```
ERROR:  column "pkcs_as_bytea" is of type bytea but expression is of type bytea[]
```

What would be the right query then?

Comment: `array_agg()` returns an array, so the error message makes sense. Why do you think you need to aggregate the bytes there?

Comment: I need to merge the blob that is on different oid rows into a single column. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stored procedure that does the magic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_oid(val oid) 
returns bytea as $$
declare merged bytea;
declare arr bytea;
 BEGIN  
   FOR arr IN SELECT data from pg_largeobject WHERE loid = val ORDER BY pageno LOOP
     IF merged IS NULL THEN
       merged := arr;
     ELSE
       merged := merged || arr;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
  RETURN merged;

END  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way which doesn't require a custom function is to use the `loread(lo_open(...))` combination, like:

```
UPDATE user SET pkcs_as_bytea = loread(lo_open(pkcs12_as_oid, 262144), 1000000) WHERE thistable.pkcs12 IS NOT NULL
```

There is a problem with this code, the `loread` function requires as the second parameter the maximum number of bytes to read (the `1000000` parameter I used above), so you should use a really big number here if your data is big. Otherwise, the content will be trimmed after this many bytes, and you won't get all the data back into the `bytea` field.

If you want to convert from OID to a text field, you should also use a conversion function, as in:

```
UPDATE user SET pkcs_as_text = convert_from(loread(lo_open(pkcs12_as_oid, 262144), 1000000), 'UTF8')
```

(`262144` is a flag for the open mode, `40000` in hexa, which means "open read-only")

Comment: Great and well explained solution.

Answer (score 1):

well, i did something like this. I have attachment table and content column with data in oid type. I migrated with four actions:

```
ALTER TABLE attachment add column content_bytea bytea
UPDATE attachment SET content_bytea = lo_get(content)
ALTER TABLE attachment drop column content
ALTER TABLE attachment rename column content_bytea to content
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `array_to_string(anyarray, text)` for text arrays, but in this case an `array_to_bytea(largeobjectarray)` to concat all sections. You have to create this function yourself, or handle this in application logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what you can do.

--table thistable --
ALTER TABLE thistable add column se_signed_bytea bytea;
UPDATE thistable SET se_signed_bytea = lo_get(pkcs_as_bytea);
ALTER TABLE thistable drop column pkc`enter code here`s_as_bytea;
ALTER TABLE thistable rename column se_signed_bytea to pkcs_as_bytea;
```