# pgloader - How to import a longblob as oid?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, pgloader

**In a nutshell**

How do you migrate a `longblob` from MySQL to Postgres using `pgloader` s.t. Hibernate is happy if the column is annotated `@Lob` and `@Basic(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)`?

**Full story**

So I'm migrating (or trying to, at least) a MySQL DB to postgres. And I'm now trying to move this table correctly:
[image]

My current pgloader script is fairly simple:

```
LOAD DATABASE
    FROM      mysql://foo:bar@localhost:3306/foobar
    INTO postgresql://foo:bar@localhost:5432/foobar

    CAST
        type int to integer drop typemod,
        type bigint with extra auto_increment to bigserial drop typemod,
        type bigint to bigint drop typemod

    ALTER TABLE NAMES MATCHING 'User' RENAME TO 'users'
    ALTER TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/./ SET SCHEMA 'public'
;
```

This is sufficient to load the data and have the foreign keys working.

The postgres table looks like this:

[image]

The `File`, however, is a java entity and its content is annotated `@Lob`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class File extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Size(max = 4096)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private String mimeType;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private transient byte[] content;

    ...

}
```

which is why the application fails to connect to the migrated database with error:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [content] in table [File];
                   found [bytea (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [oid (Types#BLOB)]
```

How do I get this migration to work?

I did try setting

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false
```

as suggested in [proper hibernate annotation for byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte) but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Hm ... I guess I can just create blobs after the fact, as suggested by [Migrate PostgreSQL text/bytea column to large object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006781/migrate-postgresql-text-bytea-column-to-large-object)

Meaning the migration script will get an extension:

```
LOAD DATABASE
    FROM      mysql://foo:bar@localhost:3306/foobar
    INTO postgresql://foo:bar@localhost:5432/foobar

    CAST
        type int to integer drop typemod,
        type bigint with extra auto_increment to bigserial drop typemod,
        type bigint to bigint drop typemod

    ALTER TABLE NAMES MATCHING 'User' RENAME TO 'users'
    ALTER TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/./ SET SCHEMA 'public'

    AFTER LOAD DO
        $$
            ALTER TABLE file RENAME COLUMN content TO content_bytes;
        $$,
        $$
            ALTER TABLE file ADD COLUMN content OID;
        $$,
        $$
            UPDATE file SET
                content = lo_from_bytea(0, content_bytes::bytea),
                content_bytes = NULL
            ;
        $$,
        $$
            ALTER TABLE file DROP COLUMN content_bytes
        $$
;
```