# Migration from SQL Server database to PostgreSQL database in corda

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, varbinary, oid, pgloader

We are using pgloader to migrate from a SQL Server database to a Postgresql database. During this process, I'm getting this exception:

> Exception during node startup: Could not read entity state from ResultSet :
> EntityKey[net.corda.node.internal.schemas.NodeInfoSchemaV1$DBPartyAndCertificate#O=N4-sh3, L=Mumbai, C=IN] [errorCode=1p2luf, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1p2luf]
>
> org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet :
> EntityKey[net.corda.node.internal.schemas.NodeInfoSchemaV1$DBPartyAndCertificate#O=N4-sh3, L=Mumbai, C=IN]

The column `party_cert_binary` is of type `varbinary(max)` in SQL Server. To what data type should this be converted in Postgresql?

I notice that some of the `varbinary` columns in SQL Server are converted to `OID` data type in Postgresql.

But pgloader by default converts all `varbinary` to bytea data type.

How should we convert `varbinary` data types to OID data type in pgloader tool?

Answer (score 0):

`bytea` is a sensible choice as an equivalent for `varbinary(max)`

Using "large objects" (aka "oid") only make sense if you have values > 1GB or if you need the streaming capabilities that large objects offer.

If in doubt, stick with `bytea`

Comment: referred  this and it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359543/pgloader-how-to-import-a-longblob-as-oid